# Text out longtable

Tags: longtable, multirow

Good afternoon

I have one problem. I have one longtable and I have setting parametres of this table. I mean I have setting size of columns. This table has three columns. In each third column I have together two lines. But just in the third column. When I write a text into this column everything is right. But when I write a longer text, text isn't cut but is out of column.

And my question is: Why is it? I have setting parametre of size of columns. What is wrong?

Thanks for explaining and help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a5paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,      
 bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\pagenumbering{alph}
%\pagenumbering{Roman}

\usepackage{ textcomp }
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\yenrule{\rule{1.3ex}{.1ex}}
\def\textyen{\renewcommand\stacktype{L}\stackon[.4ex]{\stackon[.65ex]{Y}          
{\yenrule}}{\yenrule}}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

\large
\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}p{6cm}|}
  \hline
  \textbf{come on} & \multirow{2}{*}{No tak!, Poď!, Pohni!}\\
  \textsl{[\textipa{k2m 6n}]} & \\
  \hline
  \textbf{be keen on} & \multirow{2}{*}{mať rád \textit{čo}, byť zapápený     \textit{pre čo (doing)}}\\
  \textsl{[\textipa{ki:n 6n}]} & \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that gives rise to the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose another solution, *without* multirow: U use the `\makecell` command, from the homonymous package, wich allows for line breaks in cells:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a5paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,
 bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\pagenumbering{alph}
%\pagenumbering{Roman}

\usepackage{ textcomp }
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}%

\begin{document}

\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

\large\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{|m{5cm}m{6cm}|}
  \hline
  \makecell{\textbf{come on}\\
  \textsl{[\textipa{k2m 6n}]}} & No tak!, Poď!, Pohni! \\
  \hline
  \makecell{\textbf{be keen on}\\ \textsl{[\textipa{ki:n 6n}]}}
   & mať rád \textit{čo}, byť zapápený \textit{pre čo (doing)} \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Note you don't need to define a `\textyen` command, nor load the `tfrupee` package, as `fontawesome` defines `\faYen` and `\faRupee`.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The contents in `\multirow` is put into an unbreakable `\hbox`. An inner `tabular` can be used or the second entry can be set without `\multirow`:

```
\textbf{be keen on} \newline \textsl{[\textipa{ki:n 6n}]} &
mať rád \textit{čo}, byť zapápený\newline
\textit{pre čo (doing)}\\
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

With the last version of  [multirow](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) one can replace `*`  with `=`

**Update** documentation, page 3:

> **< text >** is the actual text of the construct. If the width was set
>   explicitly, the text will be set in a `\parbox` of that width; you can
>   use `\\` to force linebreaks where you like.
>
> If the width was given as `*`
>   the text will be set in LR mode. If you want a multiline entry in this
>   case you could use a tabular or array environment in the text
>   parameter. See for example the minitab below.
>
> The width can also be
>   given as `=` when the `\multirow` entry is given in a column that has a
>   defined width, for example in a `p{}` column, an X column in tabularx or
>   a L, C, R or J column in a tabulary environment. The text will be set
>   in a `\parbox` of that width. If you give “=” in other situations, you
>   will get strange results (usually a too wide column).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}p{6cm}|}
  \hline
  \textbf{come on} & \multirow{2}{=}{No tak!, Poď!, Pohni!}\\
  \textsl{[{k2m 6n}]} & \\
  \hline
  \textbf{be keen on} & \multirow{2}{=}{mať rád \textit{čo}, byť zapápený     \textit{pre čo (doing)}}\\
  \textsl{[{ki:n 6n}]} & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to explain the difference between `*` and `=`?

Comment: @clemens   please see update, I  am sorry, this  is what  i can do.

Comment: I have copied your source code into my LaTeX file but it didn't work. I have got - 'Missing number, treated as zero.'

Comment: please  make  sure you  have  multirow version 2.0 of 2016-09-27.